# Thymeleaf/Spring Boot: "th:onclick" method being called on every refresh

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a table in my Spring Boot project, I have a button being created for each object of type Task that triggers the task. Due to the nature of how I wrote it, it seems to be calling the method every single time I refresh the page:

```
<tr th:each="task : ${tasks}">
    <td th:text="${task.getId()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${task.getName()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${task.getSchedule()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${task.getRunTime()}"></td>
    <td><button type="button" th:onclick="${task.trigger()}">Trigger</button></td>
</tr>
```

Obviously I've written it incorrectly, and I can kind of see why, assuming `${}` is just evaluating the expression inside, so my question is: what's the proper way to write that to call the method only on button click rather than evaluate the expression every time the page refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this question is already two years old and I'm sure this isn't the best solution, but in case anyone else lands here in another two years, here's a tip on how to (kind of) solve this:

It seems to me like `${}` will evaluate every expression on page, no matter where it finds it, even in an onclick. You can circumvent that by making the button a link with `th:href="@{/path/identifier}"` and creating a response method in your controller class that executes the function (in this case `task.trigger()`) and redirects you to the current view. This of course forces a page refresh when you click the button, but it makes it work as intended otherwise.